# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'TableauExtract': The specified module could not be found

Tags: java, tableau-api

```
import com.tableausoftware.TableauException;
import com.tableausoftware.common.Type;
import com.tableausoftware.extract.Extract;
import com.tableausoftware.extract.Row;
import com.tableausoftware.extract.Table;
import com.tableausoftware.extract.TableDefinition;    
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
public class TestTableau {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //delete existing extract file
        String extractFile = "extract.tde";
        deleteFile(extractFile);

        try (Extract extract = new Extract(extractFile)) {
            //create table definition
            TableDefinition tableDef = new TableDefinition();
            int columnCount = 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                tableDef.addColumn(Integer.toString(i), Type.UNICODE_STRING);
            }

            //create a table
            Table table = extract.addTable("Extract", tableDef);

            //create a sample document
            //reuse the document for each row to minimize the non-tableau CPU and memory consumption
            Random random = new Random();
            List<String> rowData = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                rowData.add(Integer.toString(random.nextInt()));
            }

            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Populating table...");

            //populate the table
            int tableRows = 4000000;
            for (int i = 0; i < tableRows; i++) {
                //convert input document to tableau row
                Row row = new Row(tableDef);
                for (int j = 0; j < rowData.size(); j++) {
                    row.setString(j, rowData.get(j));
                }

                //add the row to the table
                table.insert(row);
            }

            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(String.format("Total time (ms): %s", (endTime - startTime) /
                    1000000));

        } catch (TableauException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void deleteFile(String file) {
        File extractFile = new File(file);
        if (extractFile.exists()) {
            extractFile.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

when i am running the code i am getting exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to
>   load library 'TableauExtract': The specified module could not be
>   found.
>
> at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:194)    at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:283)     at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:244)     at
>   com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1065)     at
>   com.tableausoftware.extract.Extract.(Unknown Source)  at
>   TestTableau.main(TestTableau.java:21)

I have added the following jar files to the build path:

> tableauextract.jar jna.jar tableaucommon.jar

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you has the libraries into your buildpath, did you try to clean and build your project again?

Comment: No i didnt build again

Comment: If you are working with:

Eclipse - go to Project and press clean and then select your project.
Netbeans - right click over your project click clean and build
Intellij - same as netbeans

Comment: the same exception in intellij too. I have build the project and when i run still giving me the exception

Answer (score 0):

UnsatisfiedLinkError means that you are using a jar file that depends on native libraries being present on your system, in a location that Java knows about. From your stack trace, I'm guessing that you need TableauExtract.dll (and possibly others). The libraries that you need are available from the Tableau site here:

[Tableau SDK](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk_installing.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____3)

Once you have them installed, you need to tell Java how to find the directory where the library files live. This method depends on your OS, but on Unix you can do it by including the directory in tje LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, or possible by using the -Djava.library.path= flag